# Relationship of lambda calculus to the rest of math

Tags: lambda-calculus

I just started reading "The calculi of lambda conversion" by Church.

Church defines functions like: id x = x, and says the domain and range are understood to be as permissible as possible. Permitting even itself, id id = id

In my experience, I've always been told to specify a domain and range with the functions I've defined. And they are usually relatively limited, in contrast to id.

This is the first time I've seen functions with a domain and range this large. Are there uses for functions with wide domains and ranges in mathematical contexts other then logic or lambda calculus?

Comment: Did the edit help?

Comment: Yes. That's much clearer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The question you are trying to ask is "What is a [denotational semantics](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/denotational+semantics) for the untyped lambda calculus?"

This is a difficult problem because, as Bjorn Kjos-Hanssen said in his answer, if you try and make variables range over elements of some set $D$ you find that you must have $D \times D \cong D$ and $D^D \cong D$. Unfortunately this implies that $D$ is the singleton set and all lambda terms must represent the same function.

Dana Scott solved the problem of giving a denotational semantics to the untyped calculus with the invention of [domain theory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/domain+theory).

Comment: So if I understand this answer correctly. Untyped lambda calculus is deceptively complicated. The lambda terms are "really" continuous functions of some odd space. Is that correct?

Comment: I think you need to be more careful about the distinction between a language and a semantics for that language. Lambda terms aren't anything but strings of symbols obeying a certain grammar and rewriting rules. One may attempt to associate mathematical objects to lambda terms (give a denotational semantics) but there are many ways to this.

Comment: As you said, one way of doing this makes lambda terms into elements of a domain.

Comment: It is just like how there are many different models of the theory of groups, i.e., particular groups. It doesn't make sense to say that an element of a group is "really" a matrix even though that might be true in a particular model.

Comment: You've convinced me this is the correct answer, even though I'm not sure I understand it. Generally when I'm trying to understand properties of a function definition, the "language" isn't directly important (homomorphisms are conceptual, not syntactical). I evidently tried and failed to separate the syntax of lambda calculus from the concept of a certain function I thought was introduced. Thank you for your time. Any recommendations for learning Domain theory would be appreciated.

Comment: I would hold off on learning domain theory for a while. Church doesn't make any effort to give a denotation to lambda terms in his book. He gives an operational semantics instead (the algorithm for reducing a lambda term to a normal form).

Comment: The different kind of semantics are explained here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics_(computer_science)

Comment: If you are just trying to connect programming languages and mathematics I would learn the typed lambda calculus and look at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/903/resources-for-learning-practical-category-theory/1954#1954

Answer (score 2):

In the standard set theoretical setup, a function cannot have itself as an input. This is because the *rank* of the function is strictly larger than that of its inputs and outputs.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_universe

So when they say id(id)=id, it is meant in a more algebraic sense where composition is really just a kind of multiplication or binary operation.

Comment: So id _is_ weird. To verify your thought, I define an "application" function $id \times x = x$. Now $id \times id = id$, and we can use it $(id \times id) \times 2 = 2$. No more functions "calling themselves".

I'm still confused why I haven't seen something like this sooner. Would studying ZFC closer clarify why functions calling themselves is strange? If I wanted to use this in some mathematical context, what problems might come up?

Comment: @Polymer well, functions can still "call themselves" in a different sense, like say $f(n+1):=2^{f(n)}$.

Comment: @Polymer I guess you can try to get into Russell's paradox-like trouble like this: if you define $f(g)=1$ if $g(g)=0$, and $f(g)=0$ if $g(g)=1$, then what is $f(f)$?

Answer (score 1):

First, these are not functions. These are lambda expressions that can be artistically interpreted as functions. If you want to model lambda theory in a theory where functions are a part of the discourse, it's a different story. As it was told above, one solution is to model lambda in Set Theory. Sets have functions defined, so lambda expressions would be represented as functions. The problem is, of course, that it's impossible to model without tricks. The solution was provided by Dana Scott in the '60s. See, e.g., http://www.users.waitrose.com/~hindley/SomePapers_PDFs/2006CarHin,HistlamRp.pdf or watch him at LambdaConf, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mBjhDyHFqJY&t=2s