# To show equivalence and full faithfulness of a functor PRESERVED under an action of a finite flat algebra

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, ct.category-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, tensor-products

I have explained the two questions and then showed my effort on question $(1)$ as follows (**Please at least check my effort below and suggest to make it perfect**):

Let $R, S,T$ be three commutative rings  with $R \subset S \subset T$ and the map $ S \to T$ is faithfully flat.

Assumme a functor $F: \text{SMod} \to \text{TMod}$ between two categories, where $\text{SMod}$ is the category of $S$ modules and $\text{TMod}$ is the category of $T$-modules. (We can assume more suitable conditions if needed)

Now consider a finite flat $R$-alebra $A$.

**Questions:**

$(1)$ I want to show the functor $ \text{SMod} \otimes A \to \text{TMod} \otimes A$ is fully faithful provided the functor $F: \text{SMod} \to \text{TMod}$ is fully faithful.

$(2)$ I want to show if  the functor $F: \text{SMod} \to \text{TMod}$ is equivalence then it induces an equivalence functor $\text{SMod} \otimes A \to \text{TMod} \otimes A$.

**Note 1:** here by notation $\text{SMod} \otimes A$,  I want to mean we are taking action of the finite flat $R$-algebra $A$  (or **scalar extension** by $A$)

**Note 2:** You can improve my question by adding more conditions if necessary in order to answer question (1).

$$------------------------------------$$
**My efforts:**

Let for brevity, $\mathscr{C}=\text{SMod}$ and $\mathscr{D}=\text{TMod}$.

$(1)$ Given that $F: \mathscr{C} \to \mathscr{D}$ is fully faithful. So for any $S$-modules $M,N \in \mathscr{C}$, the functor $F$ induces the map $$F_{M,N}: \text{Hom}_{\mathscr{C}}(M,N) \to \text{Hom}_{\mathscr{D}}(F(M),F(N)),$$  which is bijective. So for any $S$-module homomorphism $f: M\to N$ in category $\mathscr{C}$, we get a unique $T$-module homomorphism $F_{M,N}(f): F(M) \to F(N)$ in category $\mathscr{D}$ by the injectiveness property. Also by the surjective property, for every $T$-module homomorphism $F_{M,N}(g): F(M) \to F(N)$ in category $\mathscr{D}$ there exists a $S$-module homomorphism $f: M \to N$ in category $\mathscr{C}$ which corresponds to each other.

Now we consider the action of the finite flat $R$-algebra $A$ on every modules of $\mathscr{C}$ and $\mathscr{D}$ such as $ M \otimes_R A$ or $N \otimes_R A$ or $F(M) \otimes_R A$ or $F(N) \otimes_R A$ etc. We can then think of the   functor $F: M\to N$ and the $S$-module homomorphism $f:M \to N$ as follows:
$$ {\color{red}{F \otimes 1}}: \mathscr{C} \otimes A \to \mathscr{D} \otimes A, \ \text{and} \ f \otimes 1: M \otimes_R A \to N \otimes_R A,$$  (where $A$ can be thought of as a category of single object (a $R$-module) along identity map $1$).

Thus it seems, by the property of product categories, $${\color{red}{(F \otimes 1)}}_{M,N} (f \otimes 1)=F_{M,N}(f) \otimes F_{M,N}(1),$$ where $1$ denotes the identity map. So it seems that the functor $F \otimes A$ induces the **bijective** map
\begin{align}
{\color{red}{(F \otimes 1)}}_{M,N}: &\text{Hom}_{C \otimes A}(M \otimes_R A,N \otimes_R A) \\ & \to  \text{Hom}_{D \otimes A}({\color{red}{(F \otimes 1)}}(M \otimes_R A), {\color{red}{(F \otimes 1)}}(N \otimes_RA)), \end{align} which answer question (1), I think. Perhaps we can consider the following diagram for better understanding:
\begin{align}
\matrix{
\text{SMod} & \overset{F}{ \longrightarrow} & \text{TMod} 
\cr  \downarrow  && \downarrow 
\cr \text{SMod} \otimes A & \overset{{\color{red}{F \otimes 1}}}{\longrightarrow} & \text{TMod} \otimes A}
\end{align}

Any comment on this approach.

**Edit:** The flatness property of $A$  and faithful flatness of the map $S \to T$ is enough to get the above bijective map to my intuition

Comment: Protip: Starting your question with "need help to..." is redundant. If you didn't need help, you wouldn't be asking a question!

Comment: @TimCampion, thanks, I have corrected the title. Can you please at least hint at the 2nd question regarding equivalence?

Comment: The question formulation seems odd to me because $F$ is just any old functor, not connected to the hypotheses like $S \subset T$ being faithfully flat. But a fully faithful functor $F: C \to D$ is an equivalence iff it is essentially surjective on objects, where "essentially surjective" means every object $d$ of $D$ is isomorphic to $F(c)$ for some object $c$ of $C$. If $F$ is essentially surjective and if I have understood your notation, then $F \otimes 1$ is essentially surjective as well, so (1) implies (2).

Comment: @ToddTrimble, Thanks a lot for your comment. The question 1 might be a more general or more restrictive  question that means we can add more suitable conditions "but" I have assumed some set up at least to state the question. Anyway, can you please tell me what type of functor $F$ will do the job in question 1 ?

Comment: If you're not referring to the extension of scalars functor, tensoring with $T$ over $S$, then I don't know what else you'd be referring to. On the other hand, for that to be fully faithful doesn't seem too common. So I'm not sure. I think maybe you should think about it some more, since you know better what the outlying context is.

Comment: Todd seems to have understood the explanation of the nonstandard notation $SMod \otimes A$ but I haven't. I might be able to guess if I were to dig through the argument below the line.

Comment: @TimCampion, ok, we can think about the product category where $\text{SMod}$  is the category of $S$-modules and $A$ is being treated as a single object category consisting of $A$ itself. Better we can replace $A$ by a groupoid or monoid. That is what I am thinking

Comment: @Masmath If $SMod \otimes A$ is meant to denote the product category of the category $SMod$ and the category $A$, then (1) and (2) are true in complete generality -- all of the other details are irrelevant. That is, if $F: C \to D$ is a functor and $A$ is a category then the induced functor $F \times 1_A: C \times A \to D \times A$ is is fully faithul (respectively, an equivalence) if and only if $F$ is fully faithful (respectively, an equivalence). You can check this directly from the definitions.

Comment: @TimCampion,Thanks. You said to follow the definition. I did the exactly that in the above. That is, I have tried to show  that the induced map  $(F \otimes 1_A)_{M,N}$ on Hom-sets of $SMod \otimes A$ is injective and  surjective iff    the induced map $F_{M,N}$ on the Hom-sets of $SMod$ is injective and surjective. Do you think this trivial ?

Comment: @Masmath I think your proof is correct (and trivial) if $SMod \otimes A$ is really the product category, except for the part where you say "consider the action of $A$". If $SMod \otimes A$ is really the product category, then the action of $A$ is irrelevant to the discussion. So I think it's much more likely that you have misunderstood what you're supposed to be proving.

Comment: My advice is to go back and reread whatever it is you're reading and make sure you understand all the notation, definitions, etc. I would also suggest you read a bit on basic category theory where it is not mixed up with specific algebra which might be new to you. I've listed a few good books [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/302486/category-theory-for-a-set-model-theorist/302489#302489) for example. Once you have a bit more practice these things will become clearer.

Comment: @TimCampion, Thank you very much for your advice. The link is helpful